# Can't create primary partition on windows7 using diskpart

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, diskpart

Can't create primary partition on windows7 using diskpart. 
I'm trying to install ubuntu along with windows 7. When I try to create a new primary partition using diskpart it shows me error as:

Virtual Disk Service Error:
The operation is not supported by the object.
The specified command are not supported on this system.

Comment: Where are you trying to use diskpart? Recovery or live Win 7 OS? How many hard drives are involved here? I'd suggest using GParted boot disk - it's easier to use than diskpart.

Comment: I'm trying in live win OS. Only 1 HDD is there. Also I've 200GB unallocated.

Comment: So why don't you install Ubuntu in that 200GB of unallocated space? (You don't need diskpart for anything - the Ubuntu installer takes care of it)

Comment: I tried using bootable usb. but when I restart to install it doesn't show me that space. It shows me only primary partitions which are currently in use

Comment: Take a screenshot of the disk management window in windows and add it to your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sF02g7w2ADR2tLOWE5X0pfWGc/edit?usp=sharing
Check this and reply

Comment: This is what I asked for: http://www.totalpchealth.com/images/screens/articles/disk-management.gif

Comment: Sorry. Here it is.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sF02g7w2ADQmFmVDZEMm5OUFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not too familiar with dynamic disks but it might be possible that the unallocated block can't be seen because it's between other dynamic partitions. You could use GParted to move the two partitions on the right over to the left such that the unallocated block is at the end. The large amount of partitions is rather messy and unorthodox - perhaps you could consolidate them into 2-3 partitions. Generally dynamic disks are avoided in dual boot environments due to incompatability with linux.

Comment: Okay. Can you give me any link how to use GParted?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... As far as I know it is not possible to
>   install Linux on a Dynamic Disk (it's disk that are dynamic, not
>   partitions). You need to reinstall with a Basic Disk (or find some way
>   to non-destructively convert).
>
> No time to do any further research at the moment as the dogs are
>   asking for their walk, but I'll have a look around to see if I can
>   find any further info. - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/238032-50-install-linux-windows-dynamic-partition

---

> Q: I have discovered an irksome issue with some hardware. I think the
>   way to go is comparison so bear with me.
>
> I used to load Linux (name the version) on a back partition on my WinX
>   machines so that I can ease into learning about Linux before I make it
>   my primary system. I would use tools to squeeze out a partition and
>   then install Linux to this back partition. It (in this specific case)
>   would add a boot menu so that I could load either Linux or WinX during
>   the boot process.
>
> Now, we come to the "issue." I got a new HP G-62 laptop (loaded with
>   Win7 and using Linux 10.4.x LTS) and decided to follow the steps above
>   and they failed. I did some investigating and discovered that the
>   system was configured to use "dynamic" disk structure and wouldn't let
>   me install Ubuntu to the partition I created due to the disk
>   configuration. Now, I don't want to re-install everything, so I did a
>   work around. I added a portable drive, loaded Ubuntu, and when I boot
>   now I go to the BIOS select the portable drive to get Linux, a real
>   pain, but it works.
>
> The question, can I get Linux to install into a dynamic disk on a
>   partition, and get the boot menu like the good old days?
>
> A: The simple answer to this is "no." With the creation of dynamic disks, Microsoft
>   is basically saying "There can be only one!" As far as I know, Linux
>   does not in any way support the dynamic disk structure. Because of
>   that you can always convert from dynamic to basic. How this is done
>   will depend upon the version of Windows you have. If you attempt to
>   try this, make sure you BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST.
>
> The easiest method for doing this is to simply virtualize Linux.
>   Install VirtualBox in Windows and then install your distribution of
>   choice that way. By virtualizing you won't harm your Windows
>   installation, and you won't have to reboot to continue trying to learn
>   Linux. For my money, virtualization is the way to go. Just make sure
>   you have plenty of RAM -- especially if you're using Windows 7 as the
>   host. - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-can-i-dual-boot-linux-on-a-dynamic-disk/

Comment: So it is. Thanks, it's very much helpful. Now I will try every possible option